# Play high C-D trill on flute

Tags: fingering, flute, trills

I have a C flute, which I recently dug out and am relearning.

I've noticed that the first trill key for C-D doesn't work as well for high C-D. There is a change in pitch and quality, much more noticeable than the change for the normal octave C-D trill.

Is there an alternate, easier (than alternating the normal C-D fingerings) way to do a high C-D trill?

Comment: My brief experience with the Clarinet is that you should be able to "bend" the note a little closer; and if it's quick enough, no one should notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@F'x [showed me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4621373#4621373) [this resource](http://www.wfg.woodwind.org/flute/fl_tr2_2.html), it displays the trill as follows:

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

The red key is what you alternate.

Comment: Your diagram shows the wrong key. The resource you link to gives the fingering shown here as an alternative, but the D is very flat.

Answer (score 7):

The 2nd trill key is used for the higher C-D trill.  Better sound quality.

Answer (score -1):

For me I always find it easier to decide which trill key to use for every piece I play... So honestly you could go either way. (although the second trill key is tuned to and E natural.)

Comment: this is a 5 year old question and your answer is "I usually just decide".  With due respect, I don't think you're adding anything here.